# Working with Booleans in Python/Intellij Idea

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am working through the Udemy course "Complete Python Bootcamp" and I am at the section on learning Booleans.  I am running intellij IDE and attempting to return a Boolean value from inequality statements.  For instance I am trying to return "False" from the line `2<1` however when I run that block of code, nothing is returned.  When I run it in Jupyter Notebook it returns a `False` Boolean, but not when I run it in intelliJ.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might have confused the feature of some interactive interpreters to display the result of the last line with an actual `print()` or `return`. Try something like `print(2 < 1)`!

Comment: Perfect, thank you!